# How to convert mantissa from decimal to binary efficiently

Tags: binary, theory

I am aware of the textbook method where we multiply the mantissa by 2 , take its integer part as the next bit, multiply the fractional part by 2 and repeat, until we get zero or reach our desired precision.

Is there an efficient algorithm to convert mantissa from base 10 to base 2 than the above mentioned algorithm?

Comment: Define efficient. This is an O(n) algorithm - some would call it efficient enough.

Comment: How about O(log n)?

Comment: Or an algorithm where I can get multiple bits with a single multiplication. It doesn't matter if it is O(n) if the constant is small enough because I don't have to convert large numbers.

Comment: I mean, cant you just do `x = your_number` and just print out it's bits? The number is internally stored as the binary so you wouldn't really be using your computer to do the conversion (it is already stored as binary).

Comment: No, this is for demonstration purpose.

Comment: I believe this is the fastest way to do it (within a few factors). You could potentially memoize certain common values so that the conversion is quicker for many conversions.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you proposed runs in `O(n)` time where n is the number of bits desired.  We cannot do better than this, because we have to somehow calculate all `n` desired bits of the output, so any algorithm must be at least `O(n)`, or else the output could not possibly contain all the desired information.